# Calling a function without input arguments in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am new to Matlab, I want to call a function in different GUI without sending any arguments( from one GUI to another).

**Example:**

gui1.m

```
function some_ui_OpeningFun(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

a = 10;
setappdata(0,'a',a);

gui2('pushbutton1_Callback'...) %<- to call the function in the second gui

handles.output = hObject;

guidata(hObject, handles);
```

gui2.m

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

b = getappdata(0,'a');
disp(a);
```

so i want to call the function `pushbutton1_Callback` from `gui2.m`.

I have tried using `gui2('pushbutton1_callback',handles,.....)` which was give in the GUID comments. But could't get it.

Can anyone tell me how to do so?

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want a function to be accessible from outside, you should place it in its own file and give the file the same name as the function, in your example `pushbutton1_Callback.m`.

Comment: @jadhachem both example above are made from GUIDE, this two are only the examples. How would i do that if i call it from a different GUI. you mean to say these two are function which are NOT.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a GUI (`gui2`) from another GUI (`gui1`), you need some reference to `gui2` in `gui1`, this can be done in several ways; for example by requiring that the figure handle to the `gui2`-object if given as an input parameter when you run `gui1` (**EDIT: when you run `gui1` you should run it with a parameter for example like this `gui1(f)`, where `f` is the figure handle for a `gui2` figure - you can get this figure handle by running `gui2` like this: `f = gui2`**) e.g.  add the following line after the `function some_ui_OpeningFun(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)`-line:

```
handles.othergui = varargin{1};
```

Then you can call the functions of the other gui as follows:

```
otherhandles = guidata(handles.othergui);
gui2('pushbutton1_Callback',otherhandles.pushbutton1,eventdata,otherhandles);
```

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Nope, not working. I tried doing that but i get 

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

`Error in Neucube>Neucube_OpeningFcn (line 104)
handles.othergui = varargin{1};

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 221)
    feval(gui_State.gui_OpeningFcn,
    gui_hFigure, [], guidata(gui_hFigure),
    varargin{:});

Error in Neucube (line 49)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});`

Comment: I tried other ways of it by doing

`Neucube('pushbutton5_Callback',hObject, eventdata, handles);`

Now the problem is that in Neucube under `pushbutton5_Callback` i have `predict_time_length = str2double(get(handles.predict_time_length,'string'));` which gets the value from gui text box. but here i get an error after I call it from diff GUI as follows

Comment: Reference to non-existent field
'predict_time_length'.

Error in Neucube>pushbutton5_Callback (line 136)
predict_time_length =
str2double(get(handles.predict_time_length,'string'));
% training persentage

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in Neucube (line 49)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in training>stop_training_Callback (line
234)
Neucube('pushbutton5_Callback',hObject,
eventdata, handles);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in training (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in

Comment: @(hObject,eventdata)training('stop_training_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

 
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Comment: I have asked the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407121/calling-gui-function-from-different-gui-in-matlab

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear enough! For my method to work, you need to give the figure handle to the `gui2`-element as an input parameter when running `gui1`eg. `f = gui2; gui1(f);`.